# jQuery Mobile Div at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

A bit of a strange request, I know.

I have a jQueryMobile page, a simple one as you can see:

```
    <div data-role="page" class="type-home"  id="home">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Our Tools</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview">
        ......
```

I need to put a Div containing a 100 px high content at the very top, outside any styling or div that jQuery Mobile uses.

How would that be done, as adding a plain Div as is just gets covered by jQuery Mobile.

I can't use an iFrame, it has to be all on one page in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting a static header-type DIV, this is what works for me.
I put a "header" with fixed height and then offset the "content" with a margin-top like below.  .ui-content is a class that is added automatically by jQM.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="somePage">
        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-b">
            <a data-role="button" href="#main" data-transition="none" data-theme="a"></a>
            <h1>Some header</h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="someDiv">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-bar {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ui-content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```